# Databricks Move Table to a particular Schema in SQL Database

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

The following pyspark code will copy data to the default dbo Schema in Azure SQL Database.

```
test2.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", 'UpdatedProducts')\
    .save()
```

However, we have multiple schemas in the database.

We have a schema called OCC. Can someone modify the code to allow us to copy data to the schema OCC?

Comment: have you tried to specify schema + table as `schema.table` or `[schema].[table]` (don't remember Azure SQL syntax)

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, thanks for reaching out.
Do you mean something like  .option("dbtable", 'OCC.UpdatedProducts')\ ?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt, your suggestion worked. So simple. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @Alex Ott, making it as an answer it will useful to other community members

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results with dbo.schema:**

[image]

If you have multiple schema then, use concatenation and making as `schema.table_name`

```
l_schemas=["OCC","dbo","one"]# list for storing your schemas
l_tables=["table1","table2","table3"] # list for storing respective tables in that particular indexed schema
for i in range(0,len(l_schemas)):
    s=l_schemas[i]+"."+l_tables[i] # concatenation and making as schema.table_name
    df.write.mode("overwrite") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
    .option("dbtable", s)\
    .save()
```

Comment: Hi SaiVamsi, I’m looking forward to checking this out. Not sure how l_tables=table1, table2 , table3 is represented in the code, but I will look into it.

Comment: hi @Patterson, regarding `l_table` and `l_schema` variable if you have multiple sql table with schema then follow concatenation process inside `l_table` I have SQL table.(ex: UpdatedProducts)